# EMU8086 dividing 32 bit number by a 16 bit number gives unexpected 0 remainder

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, emu8086, integer-division

I was trying to divide (Unsigned) **8A32F4D5** by **C9A5** using emu8086 tool. I expected the quotient to be **AF73H** and the remainder be **94B6H**. After writing the following code, I was getting correct quotient but the remainder became **0000h**. Am I missing something?

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA 
.CODE 

MAIN PROC 
; initialize DS
MOV AX,@DATA 
MOV DS,AX 
; enter your code here
MOV DX, 8A32H
MOV AX, 0F4D5H 
MOV BX, 0C9A5H

DIV BX

;exit to DOS 
               
MOV AX,4C00H
INT 21H 

MAIN ENDP
    END MAIN
```

The output in EMU8086:

[image]

Comment: Did yu find the answer of any value to you?

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a bug in EMU8086. There is no division by zero nor is there an overflow with this unsigned division ([DIV](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div)). You are correct that 0x8A32F4D5 divided by 0xC9A5 has a remainder of 0x94B6. To verify this I ran this code with Turbo Debugger in DOSBOX and got the expected results:

[image]

Had this been signed division using the [IDIV](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/idiv) instruction it would produce a division by zero exception because of division overflow.