# Calculating LCM in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, att

I have the following assembly code

```
.global _start

.section .text
_start:
    movq a, %rax
    movq b, %rbx
    imul %rbx, %rax
    cmp %rbx, %rax
    je gcd_calculated
    ja l1
    sub %rax, %rbx
    jmp _start
l1:
    sub %rbx, %rax
    jmp _start
gcd_calculated:
    div %rax
    movq %rax, (c)
```

`a,b` are quads that I need to calculate their lcm and I need to assign the result to `c`

I get wrong results with the above code and I can't spot why.

generally, i'm relaying on the the `lcm = (a*b)/gcd` so I store a*b in `%rax` and then calculate the gcd which will be stored at %eax and finally divide between them.

Comment: You calculate and compare `a * b > b` every time thru your loop, and never change `a` or `b`. That looks like an infinite loop (most of the time).

Comment: If `a, b` are 64-bit, then the LCM may not fit in a 64-bit result. Consider the values: `a = 2^63 - 1`, and `b = 2^62`, then: `gcd(a, b) = 1` (co-prime), and `lcm(a, b)` is a 125-bit result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like 1201ProgramAlarm said, you are calculating and comparing the original values of `a` and `b` in each iteration of your loop. If you want to follow your current approach, you would have to store these values in memory each time before looping.

What I would actually do instead is just do the gcd calculation first and then calculate `(a*b)/gcd` at the end.

```
_start:
    movq a(%rip), %rbx
    movq b(%rip), %rcx
gcd:
    cmp %rbx, %rcx
    je gcd_calculated
    ja l1
    sub %rcx, %rbx
    jmp gcd
l1:
    sub %rbx, %rcx
    jmp gcd
gcd_calculated:
    movq a(%rip), %rax
    xor %rdx, %rdx
    div %rbx
    imul b(%rip), %rax
    movq %rax, c(%rip)
```

Comment: Since both `a` and `b` are divisible by `g = gcd(a, b)`, it might be better to calculate `(a / g) * b` or `(b / g) * a` - this can avoid conditions where `div` raises an exception if `(a * b) / g` doesn't fit in a 64-bit `%rax` result.

Comment: I don't see anything clearing RDX before `div %rbx` takes RDX:RAX as the 128-bit dividend.  This may happen to work in a statically-linked Linux executable where registers are zeroed by the kernel before entering user-space at `_start`.  Also, you should use `a(%rip)` like a normal person for accessing static storage (if you want to load and store at all, instead of just using registers).

Comment: Also, repeated subtraction for GCD?  Normally you divide them by each other until you get a 0 remainder (like in [Greatest Common Divisor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77364) or Brett's answer); should converge much faster for some pairs of number.  (Although for some small numbers I guess this can be faster than microcoded 64-bit `div`'s startup overhead, especially on Intel CPUs before Ice Lake).

Answer (score 3):

```
/* x86-64 gcc / clang support the __int128 type: */

/*

#include <stdint.h>

unsigned __int128 lcm (uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    uint64_t u = a, v = b;

    for (uint64_t t = 0; (t = v) != 0; u = t)
        v = u % v;

    if (u != 0) /* gcd(a, b) != (0) : */
        return (((unsigned __int128) a) * (b / u));

    return (0);
}

*/

/* x86-64 Mach-O (OSX) / ELF calling conventions:
 * first arg (a) in %rdi, second arg (b) in %rsi;
 * 128-bit integer returned in %rdx:%rax [hi:lo] */

/* no caller-reserved registers or stack are used: */

        .text
        .globl _lcm
_lcm:
        movq    %rdi, %r8
        movq    %rsi, %rdi
        movq    %r8, %rcx
L_gcd:
        testq   %rdi, %rdi
        je      L_lcm         # %rcx = gcd(a, b)
        movq    %rcx, %rax
        xorl    %edx, %edx
        movq    %rdi, %rcx
        divq    %rdi
        movq    %rdx, %rdi
        jmp     L_gcd
L_lcm:                        # lcm(0, 0) returns (0) :
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        xorl    %edx, %edx
        testq   %rcx, %rcx    # if gcd(a, b) == 0, then:
        je      L_done        # %rdx:%rax = 0:0; return.
        movq    %rsi, %rax
        xorl    %edx, %edx    # %rdx:%rax = 0:b
        divq    %rcx          # %rax = (b / g)
        mulq    %r8           # %rdx:%rax = a * (b / g)
L_done:
        ret
```